# onmouseover and onmouseout both attribute on marquee tag of html does not work with React.js

Tags: html, reactjs

I have used marquee tag on my Home.js file on react.js resulting attribute on the marquee tag does not work properly or does not make any effect.

I have added  tag to publish my news on my website which would be stopped while mouse over there and again run while mouse out there.

Actually, it's not working while I go to check it on the browser.

but other attribue like scroolamount and direction works properly.

import React from 'react';
import './Home.css';

```
export default function Home() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="title">

            <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="">
            <a href=""> <h5> Welcome to my page. Visit regularly to obtain useful information </h5> </a>
            </marquee>
            </div>

            <div className="main-content">
                <div className="content">
                <div className="overview">
                    <h3>Overview</h3>
                    <div className="video-section">
                        <iframe  width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/opYAyx1Humc?autoplay=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                            {/* <video>
                                <source src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ioblgpA5eTo" type="video/youtube"/>
                            </video> */}
                    </div>
                    <div className="text-section">
                        <p> 
                        Computer science is the study of computation and information.[1][2] Computer science deals with theory of computation, algorithms, computational problems, and the design of computer systems hardware, software, and applications.[3][4] Computer science addresses both human-made and natural information processes, such as communication, control, perception, learning, and intelligence, especially in human-made computing systems and machines.[5][6][7]

                        
                    </div>

                    </div>
            

            
                <div className="newsbar-side">

                            <h3>News & Updates</h3>

                
                ***<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="up" scrollamount="4"  
                  onmouseover="this.stop();"  onmouseout="this.start();">***

                



                    <p>Inside the White House Event Now Under Covid Scrutiny</p>
                    <p>Inside the White House Event Now Under Covid Scrutiny</p>
                    <p>Inside the White House Event Now Under Covid Scrutiny</p>
                    <p>Inside the White House Event Now Under Covid Scrutiny</p>
                   Scrutiny</p>

                </marquee>


                </div>
                </div>
                

                <div className=""></div>

            </div>
            
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: please edit your question. put a minimum code and point out the precise error.

Comment: Just look over marquee tag I have marked it with **** symbol alrady. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

According to the [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

> React events are named using camelCase, rather than lowercase.

So in your case, it must be

```
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="up" scrollamount="4"  
                  onMouseOver="this.stop();"  onMouseOut="this.start();">
```

Comment: Still it does not work, I have changed it from all having lowercase to uppercase like


<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="up" scrollamount="4"  
                  onMouseOver="this.stop();"  onMouseOut="this.start();">